# Terminology surrounding functors

Tags: c++, functor, function-object

Let's take a simple functor

```
class LessThan {
public:
    explicit LessThan (int in ) : val(in) {}
    bool operator() (int param) const {
        return param < val;
    }
private:
    int val;
};
```

which I can use like this for example -

```
vector<int> myVector = factory();
size_t count = count_if(begin(myVector), end(myVector), LessThan(10));
```

My understanding of the terminology surrounding functors is that the class `LessThan` is a functor. i.e. it is a type, not an object. i.e it is abstract, not concrete.

So, what do we call `LessThan(10)`? Here, we are creating an object by instantiating the `LessThan` functor type. So, do we call it a functor object? But, functors are function objects. So, `LessThan(10)` is a function object object??

Isn't that absurd?

Comment: Objects *are* types. Or rather, they are *instances* of types. User defined classes are types and when you instantiate them you get objects of that type.

Comment: @JesperJuhl For `int a`, ...`int` is a type and `a` is an object. And the two are thus different.

Comment: If it helps, just think of it this way: `LessThan` is a _function object type_. `LessThan(10)` is a _function object_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Terminology for function objects is the same as terminology for regular objects: your functor `LessThan(10)` has a type, which is `class LessThan`.

Note that your functor is a combination of a function (i.e. "less than") and one of its arguments (i.e. `int val`). The same effect can be achieved through functor composition:

```
auto f = bind(less<int>(), _1, 10); // f is LessThan(10)
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/MT98ST)

Comment: @typetraitor That's correct. A lot of functor types represent pure functions, and thus have no state (e.g. `std::less`, `std::plus`, etc.) This makes it much easier to confuse the type and the object, because all objects of the type are essentially the same.